# "Two times as long as" versus "two times longer than"

Tags: phrase-meaning, comparison

Say, Rule 1 is 60 cm long, Rule 2 is 30 cm long, and Rule 3 is 20 cm long.

> A.  Rule 1 is **two times as long as** Rule 2.
>
> B.  Rule 1 is **two times longer than** Rule 2.

Sentence A is indisputably correct. Some English grammar books in China say that Sentence B is incorrect, however, and should be replaced with

> C.  Rule 1 is **two times longer than** Rule 3.

I beg to differ. Don't sentences A and B have the same meaning? That is, doesn't "twice as long as" mean "twice longer than"?

Comment: '[A number of] times longer than' doesn't make sense. Rule 2 is 10cm longer than Rule 3.

Comment: Normally, we would say "twice as long as sth " or twice the length of sth " instead, right? This is traceable, Cambridge Dictionary for instance.

Comment: Yes, Weather Vane has already told you that.

Comment: @KateBunting For multiples other than 2 (where we use "twice"), "N times longer" is  the idiomatic way to say it, as in Weather Vane's answer. However, for ratios less than 2 we often use percentages: "Rule 2 is 50% longer than Rule 3."

Comment: @Barmar - 'N times longer' doesn't make sense to me, though [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=times+longer%2C+times+as+long&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) shoes that it is used, but was much less common for most of the 20th century.

Comment: Does anyone confirm whether in this post " twice longer than " means the same as " twice as long as "? Still some people think " three times longer than " means " twice as long as" , but actually wrong.

Comment: Say, based on the context,  we would say " Rule 1 is three times as long as  Rule 3" or " Rule 1 is three times the length of Rule 3 " .  But, we can't say " Rule 1 is twice longer than Rule 3 " because this sentence means the same as " Rule 1 is twice as long as Rule 3" which contradicts the context( Rule1 =60cm, Rule3=20cm).

Comment: @user421993 "N times longer" is not usually considered ambiguous. However, we do get ambiguity when we say something like "X is 200% longer than Y" -- it could mean X = 2 x Y or  X = Y + 2 x Y (i.e. X = 3 x Y)

Comment: I agree. One should try his best to avoid ambiguity in conversation or writing.

Comment: @user421993 *some people think that "three times longer than" means "**twice** as long as".* I think you meant to say this instead: *some people think that "three times longer than" means "**four times** as long as".*

Answer (score 2):

Idiomatically we would say

> Rule 1 is **twice** as long as Rule 2.

Please see [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/twice)

> **twice**
> two times

But suppose it was three times? We don't say "thrice" as long, but your second version is a bit ambiguous, and for that reason we would say in this case (if the lengths were changed accordingly)

> Rule 1 is three times as long as Rule 2.

Comment: You are right. Normally, we use twice instead of two times.

Comment: I don't think so.  " Three times longer than"  is equal to " three times as long as " . Please double check.

Comment: Apologies, I contradicted what I had just written, which was not to use no. 2.

Comment: Three times longer than is four times as long as.

Comment: And some people do, or did, say "thrice as long as," although it's not as popular as it used to be": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thrice+as+long+as&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 0):

> > A.  `60 cm` is **two times as long as** `30 cm`.
>
> Sentence A is indisputably correct.

Indeed, there's no controversy that ‘as much/long as’ connotes multiplication/scaling, and that

- `60 cm` is **four times as long as** `15 cm`
- `60 cm` is **(100% / just) as long as** `60 cm`.

> doesn't "twice as long as" mean "twice longer than"?

A 160 cm twelve-year-old is a tall child (tall for a child) but not a tall *person*. Similarly,

- `60 cm` is **two times longer than** `20 cm`

technically means

- `60 cm` is **longer than** `20 cm` **by two times (of `20 cm`)**
- `60 cm` is **longer than** `20 cm` **by 40 cm**,

and does not mean

- `60 cm` is **longer than** `20 cm`, with the former being **twice *as long as*** the latter,  ❌

because ‘two times’ is being adjectival to ‘longer than’. Thus, technically,

- `60 cm` is *not* **two times longer than** `30 cm`
- `60 cm` is *not* **1½ times longer than** `40 cm`
- `60 cm` is *not* **150% longer than** `40 cm`
- `60 cm` is **50% longer than** `40 cm`
- `60 cm` is **zero times longer than** `60 cm`
- `(n+1)B` is **n times longer than** `B`.

For a more general discussion (involving ***non-positive quantities***) please refer to ["x times as many as" versus "x times more than"](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4722720/21813).

In the spirit of descriptivism, let me acknolwedge that ***in practice***, publications routinely assert that `60 cm` is **three times longer than** `20 cm` rather than that `60 cm` is **two times longer than** `20 cm`; however, I shall stop short of calling the former assertion idiomatic, because it so needlessly conflicts with the more coherent assertion.

Summing up: the phrasing ‘A is **n times longer than** B’ is, in practice, ambiguous and potentially misleading, whilst ‘A is **m times as long as** B’ is always clear.

Comment: This sounds like the sort of extraneous verbiage that ChatGPT would generate.

Comment: Haha, I see where you are coming from, but No (and actually it would be surprising for chatGPT to assert my non-majority position or to be logical). Anyhow, do try to do likewise; after all, I’m not the only one [whose view differs from yours](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/7897/484417).

Comment: Use "longer than" additively, eg *40cm longer than*. Use "as long as" if you are multiplying, eg *three times as long as*.

Answer (score 0):

For something to be x amount of times longer than something would surely mean that if x = 1 it would still be longer than the original value.

So im seeing…

The value is 1 time longer

Similarly..

The value is longer by 1 time

In other words it is twice as long

So i think saying something is 2 times longer is just something that caught on over time, Its like when people say i could care less instead of i could not care less

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).